# Error building Appcelerator project: Failed to package application: error: Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to build an application created by another developer. I have imported the project and updated the dependencies to the latest version. When I try to run, I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[ERROR] :      (skipping file '.liveviewapp.js' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[ERROR] :  E:\Projects\New_workspace\app\build\android\res\values\theme.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.skitanium'.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

The `themes.xml` file has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.skitanium" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/editText</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- AppCompat Compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Text fields -->
    <style name="editText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>   
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here are the versions I am using:

```
  <manifest android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="1.1.7">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>
```

Titanium SDK Version: 7.5.0.GA

Axway Appcelerator Studio, build: 5.1.1.201809051655

Can someone guide me what are the possible reasons for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation at: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Themes#AndroidThemes-Androidthemes

You are not allow to name your theme `theme.xml`. That will override the internal theme. So if you rename your file it should work.

Also please try `<style name="Theme.skitanium" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` without the `@style`. There is an example at https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/android_themes.html that uses it without too

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. It's actually `themes.xml`

Comment: ah ok. please try `<style name="Theme.skitanium" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked!  If I specify `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` directly in the `tiapp.xml` it compiles successfully. But with custom theme it doesn't work.

Comment: where do you set the theme? In your TSS file? Somewhere you have `@style/Theme.skitanium` where it only needs to be `Theme.skitanium`

Comment: Setting it in the `tiapp.xml` file. Tried without @style , but that also didn't worked

Comment: don't have any problem with your theme: https://github.com/m1ga/test_theme

Comment: What might be the problem then? Any other things that might cause this?

Comment: compare the code with the demo. I can't see you project and in my project it is working with your theme. So there has to be something special in your project

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it :)